# Regex function for a word containing non roman characters

Tags: regex

Is there a regex for finding words including non roman characters?

Previously I've used the following regex for finding words `/(\w+:)/` But on a word such "TVÄTT" the regex only finds the letters after the non roman character "TT". If I change the regex to `/[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]\w+:/` the letter Ä is included but not the whole word. How would i get the whole word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add these symbols to what `\w` matches (and it matched `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` as I see from your question), you just need

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9_äöåÄÖÅ]+:)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUS7Qv/1).

The `([a-zA-Z0-9_äöåÄÖÅ]+:)` is a capturing group that matches one or more occurrences of ASCII letters, digits, `_` and letters from the `äöåÄÖÅ` set.

Comment: Great solution. Seems like '/[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]+:/' would work as well. Just curious, what does 'Z0-9_' do?

Comment: Matches `Z`, `_` and digits.